# Select multiple child elements using nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
div div p:nth-child(1 to 5)
```

How can I select multiple numbers with the nth-child, so I get the child elements 1 to 5 without having to write:

```
div div p:nth-child(1),
div div p:nth-child(2),
div div p:nth-child(3),
div div p:nth-child(4),
div div p:nth-child(5) {

}
```

So it should look like this:

```
div div p:nth-child(1 to 5)
```

Comment: You can use a CSS pre-processer like SASS or LESS - but it'll only compile to the exact same thing you have written. Interesting question - why is having this on one line important to you? What do you win for putting it on one line?

Comment: A lot of useful `nth-child` tricks are summarised by [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/).

Answer (score 9):

```
div div p:nth-child(-n+5){

}
```

This will select the first 5 children.

Comment: How to select next 5 children and next one ... ?

Comment: @HamidShoja There is an explanation for what `-n+5` represents and more useful examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#examples

Answer (score 9):

```
div div p:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+5){

}
```

will select elements 1 to 5

Answer (score 5):

```
div div p:nth-child(1),
div div p:nth-child(2),
div div p:nth-child(3),
div div p:nth-child(4),
div div p:nth-child(5){

}
```

**Or**

```
div div p:nth-child(-n+5){

}
```

Comment: Sorry wrong question how can I make this to just one line? and not:

Answer (score 5):

I've attached a link to a JSFiddle that should do what you are asking, but it should look something like this:

```
li:nth-child(-n+5){
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p2aBc/1/

Comment: you can click 'set as base' in jsfiddle so u wont need to change your link :P